# How can I add unlimited field in models on admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django project that I made I just made a product model that user customize it with how much field want by what kind of product wants add, so I don't know what kind of product admin wants add to make field for it, so how can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a +and- icons like this in the picture
[image]

so whenever the admin want an extra field he just needs to press + sign

in my opinion, this is the best choice

so to do this you just need to append HTML child whenever he presses the + and removes the last child when he presses the -

example of adding in js :

```
$('#containerid').append('<input name="test">');
```

example of removing element in js :

```
$('#containerid').children().last().remove();
```

and example of handling all this values in django in view func:

```
names = request.POST.getlist('name')
```

now you have a list of data you can do whatever you need with this ,

if you want to enter all these names in database you do this :

```
inc = len(request.POST.getlist('name'))
i = 0
while i != inc:
     var = Vairs(name=names[i])
     var.save()
```

this is the basic idea, if you need anything else just comment below

Comment: can you show me your doc or usage of it on your project?

Comment: I am sorry this is a private project so I can not but I clarified the way to do this

Comment: some places are unclear for me! I would be glad if you explain to me those parts in telegram! this is my id @verico